# Summing an Integer Tree (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, data-structures, tree

I'm trying to make a function that sums up the values of a non-binary integer tree.

```
-- datastructures.hs    
data Tree a = Empty | Node a [Tree a] deriving (Eq, Show)

myNums :: (Num a) => Tree a
myNums = Node 1 [ 
           Node 2 [ 
             Node 4 [Empty], Node 5 [Empty]
           ], 
           Node 3 [
             Node 6 [Empty], Node 7 [Empty], Node 8 [Empty] 
           ]
        ]

addNums :: (Num a) => Tree a -> a
addNums Empty = 0
addNums (Node n [Empty]) = n
addNums (Node n (x:xs)) = n + (addNums x) + (addNums xs)
```

Ideally, I would like `addNums myNums` to be `36`, but this produces an error:

```
datastructures.hs:20:54:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Tree a’ with actual type ‘[Tree a]’
    Relevant bindings include
      xs :: [Tree a] (bound at datastructures.hs:20:20)
      x :: Tree a (bound at datastructures.hs:20:18)
      n :: a (bound at datastructures.hs:20:15)
      addNums :: Tree a -> a (bound at datastructures.hs:18:1)
    In the first argument of ‘addNums’, namely ‘xs’
    In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘(addNums xs)’
```

How do I counter this, and what are the best practices?

EDIT: Best practices seem to omit `Empty` altogether!  I forgot that `[]` is a valid instance of type `[Tree a]`.  So the best way to implement this is:

```
data Tree a = Node a [Tree a] deriving (Eq, Show)

addNums :: (Num a) => Tree a -> a
addNums (Node n []) = n
addNums (Node n (x:xs)) = n + (addNums x) + addNums (Node 0 xs)
```

Comment: `(addNum x) + (addNum xs)`. Can't work. `x` and `xs` are of different types here.

Comment: This doesn't work either though: `addNums (Node n (x:xs)) = n + (addNums x) + foldl1 (\ acc t -> acc + addNums t) xs`

Comment: `addNums (Node n xs) = foldl (\a -> (+) a . addNums) n xs`

Comment: Also note that your tree has redundant representation. `Node 1 []` and `Node 1 [Empty]` and `Node 1 [Empty,Empty,Empty]` all represent the same tree. Perhaps you want to change that, or at least handle the `[]` case.

Comment: Oh wow, you're right.  I don't even need `Empty` as a constructor at all.

Comment: @MarkKaravan Note that if you remove `Empty`, every tree has to include at least one element `n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the last two lines of your `addNums` definition. You have to check for the empty base case, not when the list contains a single element with `Empty` inside it. Something like this should work:

```
addNums :: (Num a) => Tree a -> a
addNums Empty = 0
addNums (Node n []) = n
addNums (Node n (x:xs)) = n + (addNums x) + addNums (Node 0 xs)
```

Note that for an empty list you are just returning `n`. And when the list has more than one elements, you recursively sum it untill it reaches the bae case (i.e the list becomes empty).

Demo in `ghci`:

```
λ> addNums myNums
36
```

Comment: It took me a minute to understand why you needed that `[]` pattern (since any `[Tree a]` has to contain at least an `Empty`, but now I see you are evaluating it against your own `Node 0`.  This seems awkward; is there a best practice for this kind of tree?

Comment: @MarkKaravan Even then you have to check for `[]` case or else your pattern match will be non exhaustive. You can abstract the entire thing using `foldl` as user2407038 has demonstrated.

Answer (score 5):

Just derive `Foldable` and use the existing `sum`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}

data Tree a = Empty | Node a [Tree a] deriving (Eq, Show, Foldable)

myNums :: (Num a) => Tree a
myNums = ...

main = print $ sum myNums
```

Comment: @Mark Karavan, [yes](http://osa1.net/posts/2015-11-13-data-repr-1.html), as well as in the other answers, it leaks. You can use `fasterSum = foldl' (+) 0` (`foldl'` comes with `Foldable` as well), but I wouldn't be suprised if it leaks too. You can open another question about efficient summing of numbers in a tree.

Answer (score 4):

A possible solution:

```
addNums :: (Num a) => Tree a -> a
addNums Empty = 0
addNums (Node n xs) = n + sum (map addNums xs)
```

In the recursive case, we have a list of trees `xs`. We can use `addNums` on each of those trees, obtaining a list of numbers. Then, we simply sum them up, and add the root `n`.